# HttpPost request including spaces fails

Tags: http, http-headers, url-encoding, html-encode

When using a HttpPost request I use UTF-8 for proper encoding. When I use a space in one of the parameters, I still get the following error:

Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Invalid redirect URI: /seek/nearest.aspx?key=Miami vice&ex=0&cFilter=9a79e6ce-3344-409c-bbe9-496530baf758&children=n

The invalid character in the URL is the space between the "Miami" and "vice".

Hmmm, I thought that the POST request is not put in the URL string.

These are the steps I take to build the HttpPost request. In the "mKeyword" is the string with "Miami vice".

1 - put the request in the NameValue list:

```
List<NameValuePair> kwNvP = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
kwNvP.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00$ContentBody$LocationPanel1$OriginText", mKeyword));
```

2 - build the URI

```
String search_url = "http://www.example.com/seek/nearest.aspx"; 
try {
    theUri = new URI( search_url);
} catch ( URISyntaxException e) { etc.
```

3 - build the post request

```
HttpPost method = new HttpPost( theUri);
method.addHeader("User-Agent", "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0) Firefox/7.0");
method.addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
method.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
method.addHeader("Accept-Language", "en");
```

4 - build the content entity

```
HttpEntity entity = null; 
try {
    entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity( kwNvP, HTTP.UTF_8);
}
catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException e) { etc
```

5 - executing the request

```
method.setEntity( entity);
HttpResponse res2 = null;
try {
    Thread.sleep( (int) (1000 * GeoTools.random( 0.1, 0.3))); 
    res2 = client2.execute(method);
    Log.v( WaypointActivity.TAG, "Status line = " + String.valueOf(res2.getStatusLine()));
} catch (Exception e) { 
    // --> Coming here ... see the exception trace
```

Can you help me solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the complete program or the real target URL I'm not 100% sure ... but this part of the error stands out:

```
Invalid redirect URI
```

That implies that your original POST request is not returning a 200 but a 301, and whatever server is handling the redirect is creating the malformed URL, not your code.

Comment: Yes, this exception is given by the DefaultRedirectHandler. 

Is there a way how I can pass the string with spaces -- so that the spaces are passed correctlly to the redirect URL? 
I see that a manual entering of the action in the HTML page is working correct.

Comment: Well catch the exception and pull out the location header, check and maybe encode it then do a new request. But I think you should be looking at the content of the redirect location, because it's probably telling you something critical like you're supposed to sign up for an api or something.

Comment: OK - thank you very much. 
This strategy - making a new request directly - seems the right way. 
API - only to a very restricted group. 

Thank you.